# How to locally store tabular data

Tags: c#, .net, windows

In my .net/c# application on windows desktop i need to locally store some statistics about the users behaviour.

This data should be read again the next time the application is running.

To simply explain the kind of data: it is basically key-value pairs.

I could use something like sqlite but i can imagine there is already something for this premade in .NET?

Comment: Just use CSV, or something?

Comment: yes, but i was thinking there is maybe something premade so that i dont have to write a CSV parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to what you want to store - for simple data objects you may use XmlSerialization  that can be stored into IsolatedStorage area, specific to appdomain, or userlevel.

for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

If it is relational then Sqlite is your option as well.

So the million dollar question is - what are you planning to store?

Comment: what i want to store is some simple tabular data. my question is more about the way how to store it. this isolatedstorage, is it only for silverlight?

Comment: You can use for desktop apps. I'd used it for Microsoft OUtlook plugins where I want to store data for each user separately. So it gives a great security framework as well. Hope it helps you more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: i cant seem to find this class in the .net 4.0 framework i am using.

Comment: You can find at System.IO.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx

Comment: Version Information

.NET Framework
Supported in: 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
.NET Framework Client Profile
Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
.NET for Windows Phone apps
Supported in: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Silverlight 8.1

Comment: thanks. actually i liked the sivlerlight approach better where i can just put key-value pairs. this would perfectly fit my needs.

Comment: I am sure people out there must have made something like this one: http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/MDSystem/Vizualization/Perspective.Core/IsolatedStorageHelper.cs

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize the state using a binary file or even JSON

Comment: my question is more about how to store it not about the format.

Comment: My answer as well, you can just create a local file on the machine and persist the data inside. This assumes you're talking about an app that runs locally on the client machine

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you want to achieve. Just keep the data? Or somehow access/process it? What you do with your data determines the data structure.

Among the others, you could put the items to array or List and access them with LINQ. Or you could use ADO.NET DataSet/DataTable, even without database behind it.

Comment: i already know about the data structure and what to do with it. this question is more about the way of locally storing it.